# Google Indexa mi web anterior

Tags: prestashop, seo

Yo tenia una el dominio xxxx.com a una web en shopify, pero luego me cambie a prestashop y lo instale en DIGITAL OCEAN y GOOGLE al escribir el nombre de mi dominio me muestra mi pagina antigua(shopify) y esa pagina ya no existe.

Me muestra esta pagina antigua:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe recalcar que si busco mi domiinio en :  https://www.whatsmydns.net/  si me muestra la IP de mi servidor actual.

Que puedo hacer para ue GOOGLE me muestre mi sitio actual y no el antiguo ?

Comment: La pregunta no tiene nada que ver con programación.

Answer (score 1):

1-Verifica que las DNS de proveedor de dominio apunten a tu nuevo Host correctamente.

2-Verifica que no hay rastros de registros CNAME o A en tu antiguo proveedor de Hosting.

3-Borra todo lo referente a tu dominio de tu antiguo host y asegurate de tenerlo configurado correctamente en el nuevo.

NOTA: si el cambio lo hiciste muy rápido e intentaste visualizar los cambios es posible que el problema sea la propagación